# bash loop over two files and one file has two key values

Tags: bash, awk

This is `file1`:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

This is `file2`:

```
value: line1
id: 12
--
value: line3
id: 20
--
value: line10
id: 22
--
value: line14
id: 8
```

I want to do this:

> compare the two files and if the second column of `value` in `file2` doesn't match the `file1`, then show the value line and id line

The expected output:

```
value: line10
id: 22
value: line14
id: 8
```

These are my failed attempts:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

for all in "$(cat file1)"
do
    for ids in "$(cat file2 | grep value | awk {'print $2'})"
    do
        if [ "$all" != "$ids" ]
        then
            echo "$ids"
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: I'm just very curious - in `awk {'print $2'}` where did you get the idea to put the `'`s inside of the curly braces `{'...'}` instead of outside of them `'{...}'`?  I don't think any answer you've received here has done that. Every once in a while we see scripts like that and I've always wondered if there's a web page or book or something suggesting people should do that (you shouldn't - the `{` and `}` are part of the awk script and the `'`s are shell constructs to delimit the script when passing it to awk on the command line, just like they delimit every other script or string in shell).

Comment: You never need `cat` and/or `grep` (and/or `sed` or most other tools) when using awk, btw - `cat file2 | grep value | awk '{print $2}'` = `awk '/value/{print $2}' file2`.

Comment: @EdMorton I read it somewhere using `{print $1'}` as an example and I use that. I had no idea there are better ways, because that way worked and then I didn't change that

Comment: I see, OK - definitely don't do that as you're putting parts of the script inside and parts outside of the delimiting quotes required by the shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} !($2 in a)' file1 RS='--\n' ORS= file2
value: line10
id: 22
value: line14
id: 8
```

Answer (score 3):

With any awk. Elements of array `f1` contain all rows of file1.

```
awk 'NR==FNR                     { f1[$0]=$0; next } 
     $1=="value:" && $NF!=f1[$NF]{ print; nr=NR }
     NR==nr+1                    { print } ' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
value: line10
id: 22
value: line14
id: 8
```

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, **NR**, **NF**, FILENAME, **FNR**](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: `f1[$0]` (no need for `=$0`) should be sufficient; test then becomes `$1=="value:" && !($2 in f1)`

Answer (score 1):

A simple `bash` solution would be

```bash
<file2 paste - - - | 
  grep -Fvwf file1 | 
  tr "\t" "\n"
```

where you

- convert your `three lines per one record` format to a 'one line per record' with `paste`
- then you use fixed string (`-F`) `grep` with word matching (`-w`), inverting the match (`-v`), taking patterns from lines in `file1` (`-f file1`)
- then you can use `tr` to get back your original format
- if you want to get rid of the `--`, use `cut` or `grep -Fv` (left as an exercise to the reader)

Take care: it is a "simple shell script" approach - works with the data you have at hand, it's not a bullet proof solution that you'd write in say Python. If there's some tab characters in `file2`, they will be gone, and if there is more strings matching lines in `file1`, you'll get false matches.